# Ceiling fan and lights not working after bulb pop

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

We have a modern Hampton Bay ceiling fan and light fixture. Recently, when I turned the lights on I heard a bulb pop and the whole thing went dead, lights and all.

I believe the capacitor in the photo is the culprit. I know I can probably replace it, but is there a chance I could bypass it and wirenut the red and white wire together?  I checked the breakers, they weren't tripped.

[image]

Comment: What are these anyway, y'all? Start capacitors? If so, and *IF you can just nut them*, the fan prob won't start anymore.

Comment: Is there a dimmer involved?

Comment: @Tyson not a traditional dimmer on the switch. It does have a wireless battery remote, which when you push the light on/off button, the lights romantically get brighter taking about one second to go from off to full brightness. There's no dimmer the user can control, but something tells me there's a dimmer built-in to create that effect.

Comment: That's the part that blew.

Comment: @Tyson which part, the capacitor in the photo?

Comment: No the wireless receiver.  Usually even when they come with a fan, it's a separate part that can be used or not, the advantage is they are also sold separately and can be easily replaced.  The capacitor is not your problem, as the existing answer says just gets the fan blades turning when the unit is first turned on, it has nothing to do with the light.

Comment: @Tyson gotcha. Where can I locate the wireless.receiver?

Comment: Normally in the canopy where the fan connects the house wiring.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a capacitor in a single phase motor circuit is to shift the phase of the start winding so the motor will start.

Otherwise a single phase motor will just sit there and hum since it will be locked up.

[Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=ceiling%20fan%20capacitor%20circuit%20diagram&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us&client=safari#imgrc=ciqRaxDYCYL7GM:) is a diagram of a ceiling fan circuit.

If you bypass or short circuit the capacitor I believe the fan motor will no longer start.

Better to replace it if it is broke.

If you disconnect it from the circuit and test it with an ohm meter a good capacitor will show zero at first and climb to infinity. Then swap your leads and it should do the same again. If it shows open or shorted it is broke.

Good luck and stay safe!